# ElasticSearch : Query Each element of list on a single field using a single Query

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I am pretty new to the Elastic Search. And I have a use case where I want to search all the elements of a list on a single field in elastic search, and If any one of them is present then retrieve the document.

For example:

```
List["Shruti","shreya","shreshtha"]
```

And Search it on

"user.Name" feild that all the documents having any one of these names is returned.

Could you please help me out with the query. 
Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example.

I created a simple index with an explicit mapping like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then added a few documents with a [bulk index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) operation:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"Shruti"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"shreya"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"shreshtha"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"name":"some other name"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"name":"yet another"}
```

Now I can query a couple of different ways. A default [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) like this will work:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "name": "Shruti shreya shreshtha"
      }
   }
}
```

You can also use a [terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) as shown below. But be careful here. Notice that the terms are all lower-case. This is because, since we didn't specify an analyzer in the mapping, the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) was used, which will convert tokens to lower-case.

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "terms": {
         "name": [
            "shruti",
            "shreya",
            "shreshtha"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used in the example:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/e4f5a276aa59fb62e2e0207eb6199070014f0650